# How to check where is this error on laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi there i have an error on laravel but i don't know where is, this error make me website on error 404 , with another error HTTP 500

```
[26-Feb-2019 18:10:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF), expecting end of file in /home2/website/website.com/storage/framework/views/6a75bc263740fca85e4609e4affe4f57142c2c3a.php:181
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/website/website.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/home2/website...', Array)
#1 /home2/website/website.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(142): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('/home2/website...', Array)
#2 /home2/website/website.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(125): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#3 /home2/website/website.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(90): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
#4 /home2/website/website.com/storage/framework/views/e5516c2faf25e2e2a432f5486f5485d6792013e9.php(53): Illuminate\View\View->render()
#5 /home2/website/website.com/vendo in /home2/website/website.com/storage/framework/views/6a75bc263740fca85e4609e4affe4f57142c2c3a.php on line 181
[26-Feb-2019 18:10:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF), expecting end of file in /home2/website/website.com/storage/framework/views/6a75bc263740fca85e4609e4affe4f57142c2c3a.php:181
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/website/website.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/home2/website...', Array)
#1 /home2/website/website.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(142): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('/home2/website...', Array)
#2 /home2/website/website.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(125): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#3 /home2/website/website.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(90): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
#4 /home2/website/website.com/storage/framework/views/e5516c2faf25e2e2a432f5486f5485d6792013e9.php(53): Illuminate\View\View->render()
#5 /home2/website/website.com/vendo in /home2/website/website.com/storage/framework/views/6a75bc263740fca85e4609e4affe4f57142c2c3a.php on line 181
```

Comment: Please include the code that is throwing the error. It is even better if you include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Just read the error that's beside the date posted.

`HP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF), expecting end of file in /home2/website/website.com/storage/framework/views/6a75bc263740fca85e4609e4affe4f57142c2c3a.php:181`

So in one of the views that's generated, there is an unexpected endif on line 181.

This file: 6a75bc263740fca85e4609e4affe4f57142c2c3a.php is the one that's generated, you'll have to look into this file in the storage/framework/views/ folder. From there, you can figure out the actual view (in your resources folder) that it's created from. The real problem will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the first line of the error log `[26-Feb-2019 18:10:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF), expecting end of file in /home2/website/website.com/storage/framework/views/6a75bc263740fca85e4609e4affe4f57142c2c3a.php:181`
.

Seems that you forgot to put an @endif directive on the view you're trying to access.

For more, read here: [Control Structures](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#control-structures)

Answer (score 0):

Add Bugsnag to your application to automatically detect handled and unhandled Laravel errors.

[Bugsnag integration Laravel  guide](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/php/laravel/)